# Traversing 9 levels up in jQuery

Tags: jquery, traversal

A click event occurs on a href tag, and I need to reference the class of a  that is 9 levels up,

so:

```
<div class="blah" id="234">
 <div>
     <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
             <div><a href=""></a>
```

The only way I know is to call parent() 9 times, what else can I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can supply a selector via the parents function

```
$(a).click(function() {
   var theIdIs = $(this).parents("div.blah").attr("id");
});
```

Comment: And you can either do div.blah:first or .slice(0,1) to just get the closest one. (E.g if you want the closest div and there are more divs outside.)

Comment: ooh didn't know about slice, nice!

Answer (score 4):

Also if your using jQuery 1.3+ you can use the [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) method

```
$('a').click(function() {
   if ($(this).closest("div.blah").hasClass("blah"))
   {
      // Do something with it
   }
});
```